# Locking Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

To make a long story short, I need to lock my Xbox when I'm away from the house to prevent my youngest sibling from getting into it on the occasions he's left home alone.  Is there a way to lock it so that he can't use it?  I searched through settings on the console but found nothing to indicate a way to lock it, such as a password required to boot.  Obviously I could do something like take the power brick but I want to check for a better way.

Comment: If you want to make sure he doesn't play your games set up a family setting. So your child has to put in a password every time he wants to play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there's no trivial way to software-lock the use of the Xbox 360 short of modding it. Taking the brick or AV cable is probably your best bet.

Comment: Looks like I'll be taking the brick then.  I was hoping the Xbox would have something similar to a boot password but that was probably asking a little much.

Comment: @sommerjj It may, but if it does the Xbox's security model doesn't allow us to access it—that's why accessing that kind of thing would require modding.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a parental control passphrase and set the lowest ranked game that he can play to EC (Early Childhood). This worked for my brothers when I was younger and needed to go do something. Just dont make the code ABXY and you should be fine. Although, taking that brick is ultimately the end all, be all of security.

Comment: Ironically Netflix wasn't around then so I have not tested the applications side of this but I'm sure you can limit the play time etc.

Comment: It's honestly easier just taking the brick, (or just the cord that comes off the brick) than trying to set that up and having to undo it and put it back on constantly when I use it.